# Align tab Collapsing with Twitter Bootsrap

Tags: css, tabs, twitter-bootstrap

I cant align the tab collapsing from the Tab on the top.

Here my case : http://jsfiddle.net/PbRck/

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: You want to place the button to collapse the tab at the top of it, right? Just move the button before the collapsing tab in the DOM. http://jsfiddle.net/PbRck/2/

Comment: No i want the number in tab collapsing aligned from the number in the tab on the top. It should look the same tab when it collapses down. You got the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define width for cells, like I did for the first one (http://jsfiddle.net/PbRck/3/) or it will be calculated related to the content by the browser.

Comment: You apply <th width="30%">Fondo/Sociedad</th> and the columns 2 and 3 are alligned perfectly, but how i define the width for the cells?  Sorry for my poor and not consistent answer

Comment: In fact only the two first columns are aligned, you have to define a width for the others to be aligned properly, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/PbRck/4/

You need to define the width only once per column, the other cells inherit the style.

Comment: Thanks LeBen, you have been very useful